# Android FlipView Scrolling Back and Front Page with Button

Tags: android

I want to flip between two fragment with button click.and stop touch action.
using
 [android-flip](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip),
[issue link](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip/issues/90).

**Sample of my code**

```
public class FlipFragmeent extends Fragment{

private int currentFragmentIndex;

@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    flipView = new FlipViewController(inflater.getContext(),
            FlipViewController.HORIZONTAL);*emphasized text*
    //flipView.setFlipByTouchEnabled(false);
    flipView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) battleActivity
                        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.fragment_next, null);
                 ((Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.next)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flipView.refreshPage(currentFragmentIndex);
            currentFragmentIndex++;
             if(currentFragmentIndex == 4)
             currentFragmentIndex = 0;
        }
    }));
                        return convertView;
        }
    });
    return flipView;
}
```

**BUT** that does not work any help?

Comment: For information, in the Material Guideline:  
**Cards do not flip to reveal information on their back.**
[Google Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html)

Comment: I want to switch between two fragment content with flip animation effect>